# How is this sentence correct? "How does this machine work?"

Tags: questions

Which is the correct one, and why?

- How does this machine work?
- How does this machine works?
- How this machine works?

Comment: The linked question explains how auxiliary and infinitive verbs work in this sort of sentence.

Comment: And what about the "How this machine works?" sentence?

Comment: That's completely wrong. When a question starts *how* it must use a modal auxiliary verb ("How can I...", "How do I...", "How may I...") if it is not to sound archaic -- and only certain archaic forms are acceptable; the modal auxiliary always works. [An archaic form would be "How works this machine?" -- note where the verb comes. But that sort of archaic form is **not** recommended nowadays.] If you're learning English you may find our sister Stack Exchange site [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: _How does this machine work?_ has no modal auxiliary. _Wh_-Question Formation requires an auxiliary verb to invert with the subject, unless the _Wh_-word is the subject already. Modals always work, as you note, but so do _be, have,_ and _do_.